# Get collection with view count from and to

Tags: magento2, sql

I'm trying to get a collection with all the product, and add the view count but only for the last 3 month.
here is me request to get all the product

```
$this->getSelect()->reset()->from(
                ['e' => $this->getProductEntityTableName()]
            )->joinLeft(
                ['report_table_views' => $this->getTable('report_event')],
                'e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id',
                ['views' => 'COUNT(report_table_views.event_id)']
            )->group(
                'e.entity_id'
            );


if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
            $this->getSelect()->where('report_table_views.logged_at >= ?', $from)->where('report_table_views.logged_at <= ?', $to);
        }
```

Result

```
product 1 - 10 view
product 2 - 5 view
```

expected result

```
 product 1 - 10 view
 product 2 - 5 view
 product 3 - 13 view
 product 4 - 7 view
```

product 3 and 4 get cut out because of the `where` condition. I would like the `where` condition to only apply to the `COUNT(report_table_views.event_id)`

Answer (score 0):

If found the solution, I needed to add the condition `AND` on the join:

```
if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
    $this->getSelect()->reset()->from(
        ['e' => $this->getProductEntityTableName()]
    )->joinLeft(
        ['report_table_views' => $this->getTable('report_event')],
        'e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id AND report_table_views.logged_at >= "'.$from.'"  AND  report_table_views.logged_at <= "'.$to.'"  ',
        ['views' => 'COUNT(report_table_views.event_id)']
    )->group(
        'e.entity_id'
    );

}
```